# Getting fatal RPC error when attempting to push

Tags: git, github, push, rpc, git-push

Whenever I try to push my Unreal Engine 5 project to Github, I get a fatal RPC error. Here is the console output from Git:

Enumerating objects: 4616, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4616/4616), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4012/4012), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 55 OpenSSL SSL_read: OpenSSL/3.1.2: error:0A0003FC:SSL routines::sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (4616/4616), 1.53 GiB | 24.78 MiB/s, done.
Total 4616 (delta 1376), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

I set the http.postBuffer to 524288000, but it doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: Are you trying to push through a proxy? How long did that take?